# vite4 sass can't work with pnpm menoRepo?

Tags: sass, vuejs3, vite

at the top package.json, added sass as devDependencies.
and with scirpt:

```
"dev": "pnpm -r --parallel --filter='./apps/*' run dev",
    "admin": "pnpm -r --parallel --filter='./apps/admin' run dev",
    "merchant": "pnpm -r --parallel --filter='./apps/merchant' run dev",
    "clean": "pnpm -r --filter='./apps/*' run clean && rimraf node_modules",
    "build": "pnpm --filter='./apps/admin' run build && pnpm --filter='./apps/merchant' run build"
```

In the workspace apps(merchant admin) folder's package.json both contains script:

```
"dev": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 vite",
"clean": "rimraf dist && rimraf node_modules",
"build": "rimraf dist && NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 vite build",
```

when the first time execute the command:

```
pnpm i
pnpm run build
```

it cloud build the first admin package success.  but the second "merchant" build reported an Error: Preprocessor dependency "sass" not found. Did you install it?

also execute the pnpm run dev  It report the same error.
but when i execute pnpm run admin, pnpm run merchant on two independent terminal. can boot success.

whether is there some bugs with vite + pnpm  ?

or is there any best practice example code which use vite pnpm menorepo and typescript ?

tried the step

```
pnpm run clean
pnpm i
pnpm --filter='./apps/admin' run build
```

and the clean again

```
pnpm run clean
pnpm i
pnpm --filter='./apps/admin' run build
```

this step can build success both apps.